# VueJS Element-UI Table event @row-contextmenu is not working on iPhone

Tags: vuejs3, contextmenu, right-click, element-ui

In my VueJS application, I have a right-click functionality on each row of the table. One small popup with 3 options is there. For this, I have used Element-UI Table event `@row-contextmenu` which works on Windows desktops, laptops, and Android phones (touchscreen devices) but not on the iPhone. The code is like this :

```
<el-table
        @sort-change="sortChange"
        ref="userManage"
        :data="userData"
        style="width: 100%"
        @row-dblclick="dbClickMenu"
        @row-contextmenu="rowContextMenu">
 <el-table-column> ... </el-table-column>
 </el-table>
```

If I check `@row-dblclick="dbClickMenu"` and `row-click="rowContextMenu"` this works but only `@row-contextmenu` does not work. I tried to find the solutions and also tried the events `@touchstart` and `@touchend` but failed. Please suggest to me the possible solutions for this.